# Can Vim bind a keystroke to a particular numerical prefix?

Tags: vimrc

Some of my files are fold-heavy. I use the following to protect any fold configurations I have when I 'O' into a new line:

```
nnoremap O O.<esc>
```

I would like to know if adding the following special case (i.e. while preserving above behavior) is possible.

```
nnoremap [int]O [int]O
" Let [int] be some int greater than 1.
```

The resulting behavior is that a period is included in the newline when [int] = 1, but and a period is not included in the newlines when [int] > 1.

Thank you.

Comment: See the section on counts directly under `:help map-examples`. IOW it's automatically the case

Comment: You are right, but I misdefined the question. Please see updated post.

Comment: Not sure I understand the point of the mapping and how that helps preserve folds... In any case, to have the mapping only trigger when the count is one or absent, you can use `nnoremap <expr> O v:count > 1 ? 'O' : 'O.<Esc>'`. Is that what you're looking for? If so, let me know, I'll turn it into an answer...

Comment: It's missing a thing, I'd like for the int to pass through to the resulting keystroke. Concretely, I would like the false value of the ternary operator to be [int]O, not just 'O'. I tried this and failed: nnoremap <expr> O v:count > 1 ? '<C-r>=v:count<CR>O' : 'O.<Esc>'

Comment: Regarding the context of this mapping -- I have a custom fold expression based on the indent count. If I hit O<esc> within something that has 5-10 fold levels, then everything below gets unfolded.

Comment: Isnt that just because O-esc leaves the line completely empty, throwing away the indent from O? I think people sometimes use a random key and backspace to fix that... I’ll have to find the related Q, though it doesnt mention counts at all IIRC

Comment: Right, but actually, since you mentioned it, you don't even need random key and backspace at all. It'll open fine, it's just when <esc> is hit in that newline that indents break. The conditional-on-count logic is because there are times when I just want to create some whitespace buffer outside of nested code/text/etc. Honestly though, now that I've laid it all out, I think I'm good with what I got. Just going to use my own noggin a little more rather than lean on the Vim. Thanks Ben.